# Preprocessor blocks not detected in J2ME project (Netbeans 6.9.1)

Tags: java, blackberry, netbeans, java-me, preprocessor

I have a problem with my brand new installation of NetBeans 6.9.1. The preprocessor blocks are detected as regular comments and are not highlighted in green color, and automatically updated depending on the configuration and abilities I select.

I have installed: 
NetBeans 6.9.1 
Java ME package (mobility plugin) 
Blackberry plugin (to be able to add blackberry jde platforms)

I have created a Mobile Application project.

The problem is that when I use the preprocessor syntax I have always been using it is not detected. 
//#if and //#endif are all detected as regular comments.

I have checked "Use preprocessor" in the General tab under project properties, but no use...

How can I fix this? It is driving me crazy as I have a project I created a year ago with netbeans 6.5, with preprocessor blocks all over the place, and they are not detected

Thanks

Comment: +1 for using a preprocessor with Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, problem solved.

When you install Netbeans enabling the checkbox "Features on demand", you tell netbeans that the modules you install can be enable on demand. So you have later to manually click "Activate" the Java ME module. This seems to give problems not activating everything you need.

I reinstalled Netbeans unchecking "Features on demand" so JavaME module is activated by default and not manually. Now preprocessor blocks are detected and parsed.

Damn Netbeans...